# "Run as Administrator" starts in normal user when UAC is turned off

Tags: windows-7, uac, administrator, runas, process-elevation

I am just wondering why on some (but not all) of my systems running Windows 7 the entry "Run as Administrator" in Windows Explorer context menu doesn't work. For example, I right-click on cmd.exe, select "Run as Administrator", and the process is started as a default user.

That seems only to happen when I turn UAC off (lowest level of the slider). However, on many other systems that also have UAC turned off, this works anyway.

Which settings do I need to make this work again? Honestly, I don't have a clue why it works on some systems, while it doesn't on others. Can you explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The **Run as Administrator** option does nothing when UAC is disabled.

- if the user is a standard user, the application is launched with standard privileges
- if the user is an administrator, the application is launched with administrative privileges